# Combo Box Select

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have `Combo Box` and i want to make sure that a user cannot type anything outside the letters in the `Combo Box`. I have tried handling the `Key Down` Event of the `Combo Box` but it doesn't work.

This is what i have tried

```
    private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string regexString = "^[A-Z]";
        Match matches = Regex.Match(comboBox1.Text, regexString);

        if (!matches.Success)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Please is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Applying the DropDownStyle=DropDownList?

Comment: Have you looked at the PreviewKeydownEvent which would allow you to prevent users from typing chars that are not letters. Also make sure you look at the character typed and not the content of your checkbox

Comment: i dont think it prevents user from right click and paste text. use drowpdownstlye as steve suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply setting the [DropDownStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle.aspx) property to **DropDownList** will force the user to select only from the items already present in the combobox and typing the letters will select the corresponding item. So you can remove any code written to force an automatic selection

Do not forget to set also  **AutoCompleteMode** to **Suggest** or **SuggestAppend**.